# How to make a dictionary loop back to the start in python?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, zip

The following code in python is supposed to take a keyword and a message inputted by the user, add the alphabetical values together(so a message of aaa and keyword of bb would equal ccc) I can sum the message and keyword so that it equals 3,3,3 but I don't know how to switch this back to letters.

```
import string
step = 1
keywful=""
values = dict()
values = {letter: index for index, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)}
keyw=input("Enter your keyword for en/decryption")
msg=input("Enter your message for en/decryption")
eord=input("Enter e for encrypt or d for decrypt")
mapkeyw = [values[letter] for letter in keyw]
mapmsg = [values[letter] for letter in msg]
tot = [x + y for x, y in zip(mapkeyw, mapmsg)]
print(tot)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Be advised that I cannot use the chr and ord functions as it needs to be the alphabetical values(a=1,b=2,c=3 etc)

Comment: you can use `print ord(input_alphabet)-96` and you will get `a = 1` , `b = 2` ..... `z = 26` , However `-96` must be used only with **lowercase characers**

Comment: Can you define your problem statement clearly ?

Comment: exists a problem, if you has 555 "eee" then response is  (555) -> (444)(111) or (555) -> (333)(222) ..... (eee) -> (ddd)+(aaa) or (ccc)+(bbb) .... please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

```
print(''.join([string.ascii_lowercase[i-1] for i in tot]))
```